# ffmpeg streaming to youtube

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, streaming

I've used the following command to stream mp4 file to youtube :

```
ffmpeg -re -i merge.mp4 \
-c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -maxrate 3000k \
-bufsize 6000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ac 2 \
-ar 44100 -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<MYKEY>
```

I see the ffmpeg streams the data like that:
[image]

but yet the youtube streaming page shows nothing yet received:
[image]

Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: Streaming to YouTube is the worst. Some things to consider, make sure your feed has an audio channel (it looks like it does), and also, make sure you have the `livestreaming/dashboard` page open and finished loading **before** you start streaming to YT. (otherwise YouTube just pretends you're not streaming anything, even if you do everything else right. It's maddening)